# KnockoutJS - Observable Array property update,the parent's status should be changed

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to change the array of person property “father”，and then the parent's status should be changed,but it not works.
   I used ko.computed update "person's property father,",then the parent's "status" should be change as "true".

what am I doing wrong?

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:vm">
        <li>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:age" />
            <input type="text" data-bind="value:status" />
            <!-- ko foreach:person-->
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:father" />
            <!-- /ko -->
        </li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ps = [{"name":"gsh","status":false,"age":12,"person":[{"father":"a"},{"father":"b"}]},{"name":"zx","status":false,"age":"22","person":[{"father":"c"},{"father":"d"}]}];

    function Person(p){
        this.father=ko.observable(p.father);
    }

    function Pros(p){
        this.name = ko.observable(p.name);
        this.age = ko.observable(p.age);    
        this.person = ko.utils.arrayMap(p.person,function(pe){
            return new Person(pe);
        });     
        this.status = ko.observable(p.status);
        this.status = ko.computed(function(){
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.person,function(pe){
                pe.father();    
            });

            return true;
        },this);
    }
    var vm = ko.utils.arrayMap(ps,function(p){
        return new Pros(p);
    });
    var VModel = ko.observableArray(vm);

    ko.applyBindings(VModel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems: first, you're overwriting the `status` attribute:

```
this.status = ko.observable(p.status);
this.status = ko.computed(function(){});
```

Not only does this not have the desired effect, but overwriting observables is quite risky, because it leads to bugs that are not easy to track down. For example, if you bind an `<input>` to an observable and later overwrite that observable with something else, the binding will silently stop working.

Also, `ko.utils.arrayMap` returns an ordinary array, not an `ko.observableArray`. This means that `this.person` is not observable, and your `computed` that iterates over it will not notice if elements are added or removed to it. This *might* work in your case if you time it right and do not add or remove anything, but it's something to keep in mind.

The third issue is that your `computed` also probably does not do what you want it to:

```
this.status = ko.computed(function(){
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.person,function(pe){
    pe.father();    
  });

  return true;
},this);
```

This iterates over all persons, discards the result and then always returns true.

All together, I would try to rewrite your code like this:

```
var ps = [{"name":"gsh","status":false,"age":12,"person":[{"father":"a"},{"father":"b"}]},{"name":"zx","status":false,"age":"22","person":[{"father":"c"},{"father":"d"}]}];

function Person(p){
    this.father=ko.observable(p.father);
}

function Pros(p){
    this.name = ko.observable(p.name);
    this.age = ko.observable(p.age);
    this.person = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(p.person, function(pe){
      this.person.push( new Person(pe) );
    }, this);

    this.status = ko.computed(function(){
        var allTrue = true;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.person(), function(pe){
            if (!pe.father()) {
              allTrue = false;
            }
        });

        return allTrue;
    },this);
}

var vm = ko.utils.arrayMap(ps,function(p){
    return new Pros(p);
});

var VModel = ko.observableArray(vm);
```

If you do not need support for Internet Explorer older than 9, your `status` computed can be written more succinctly with the help of [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
this.status = ko.computed(function(){
  return this.person().every(function(p) {
    return p.father();
  });
}, this);
```

Comment: thanks,I had solved this problem, but I changed somewhere,like this:               var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable(p.name);
   self.age = ko.observable(p.age); 
   self.person = ko.observableArray();
   ko.utils.arrayMap(p.person,function(pe){
    self.person().push(new Person(pe));
   });